# Competitions for show innovations and gain visibility

Tags: ros, industrial-robot

I'm looking for robotics competitions suitable for companies that desire show their innovations and gain visibility. I know about DARPA Robotics Challenge and RoboCup, but I'd love suggestions for global and European competitions across domains like industrial, medical, and space robotics. Any insights, including objectives, evaluation criteria, and dates, would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some *small* competitions I know of. But the might be too small for companies, or mainly focused around students and companies might be forbidden.

#### [Field Robot Event](https://www.fieldrobot.com/)

> The international Field Robot Event is an annual outdoor and online contest on a (virtual) agricultural field, where students and their supervisors compete within several tasks in autonomous navigation and other operations.
> The FRE has been founded by the Wageningen University in 2003 in order to motivate students to develop autonomous field robots. Now we are looking forward to the 20th event and hope to enjoy creative and functional solutions. The agricultural tasks will be challenging for the robots and their students, but behind engineering skills we want to promote meeting international colleagues ‐ and of course having fun during the contest!

Here the Website of [Kamaro Engineering](https://kamaro-engineering.de/), which might be interesting. Some blog posts are in English as well.

#### [Robotour](https://robotika.cz/competitions/robotour/en)

> Robotour — robotika.cz outdoor delivery challenge, is originally Czech contest of autonomous robots navigating on paved park roads. Robots carrying payload (five liter barrel) get extra points. The contest is annual on falls. The first year was in 2006 in Prague, park Stromovka.

#### [Carolo-Cup](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/carolo-cup/)

> The Carolo-Cup is a student competition, providing student teams with a platform for the design and implementation of automated RC cars. The main challenge is to implement cutting-edge algorithmic solutions for vehicle control and environment perception, based on a realistic application scenario.
> In the annual competition, the students will present their solutions to a jury from academia and industry, while competing with other international teams from different universities.

Some Teams: [KITcar](https://kitcar-team.de/), [Spatzenhirn](https://www.uni-ulm.de/in/spatzenhirn/)

#### [Formulastudent](https://www.formulastudent.de/fsg/)

> Students build a single seated formula style car with which they can compete against teams from all over the world.

There is a driverless format as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ariac

The ARIAC competition is imo. interesting, as it is an industrial setting:

https://www.nist.gov/el/intelligent-systems-division-73500/agile-robotics-industrial-automation-competition

https://ariac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

#### Virtual RobotX

The upcoming VRX competition is the virtual counterpart of the Maritime RobotX Challenge:

https://robotx.org/programs/vrx-2023/

https://robotx.org/programs/robotx-challenge-2022/

I think this is purely aimed at universities though.

#### Humanoid Robot Wrestling Competition

Also upcoming is the IROS 2023 Humanoid Robot Wrestling Competition:

https://github.com/cyberbotics/wrestling

#### European Robotics League

There should also be a 'Smart City' competition in the UK coming September, but I did not find a lot of further info. This is open to companies.

https://eu-robotics.net/eurobotics/activities/european-robotics-league/#erl-news

#### Rami

There's the Rami campaign for arial robots:

https://metricsproject.eu/inspection-maintenance/aerial-campaigns-2023/

#### Robocup

Obviously also the robocup:

https://www.u-bordeaux.fr/en/about-us/our-strategy/institutional-projects/artificial-intelligence/robocup-2023

#### ELROB 2024

The European Land Robot Trail also seems interesting:

"The military ELROB, which takes place for the ninth time now, enables you to get a glance at the latest R&D in the area of unmanned outdoor/off-road ground systems. The scenarios have been developed in closest co-operation with the military users and reflect the up-to-date requirements of the forces. This event offers the fantastic opportunity to mingle with the international experts from the user community, the industry and the R&D sector."